# Use select filed result on LEFTJOIN string

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use `id_program` result from the `availability` table inside a string in LEFTJOIN, is it possible?

I tried using this `{post.id_program}` but its not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM availability post
    LEFT JOIN postmeta meta5 ON meta5.post_id = post.id_post 
        AND meta5.meta_key = 'items_iti_port_{post.id_program}_nights_iti_port'
WHERE post.id_post=462
```

EDIT:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeb4a7/3

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Try with [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel any example of how to use CONCAT() inside a string?

Comment: If all else fails [you could look at the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways..

Using [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
meta5.meta_key = CONCAT('items_iti_port_', post.id_program, '_nights_iti_port')
```

With [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
meta5.meta_key = REPLACE('items_iti_port_%_nights_iti_port', '%', post.id_program)
```